Struct with dynamic fields
I have a code to convert json to struct using serde. But, got stuck at a json with dynamic keys.
The json will contain the price list. it can vary and will be dynamic
{"Price 1":{"price":9.99,"qty":1.0}, "Price 2":{"price":8.99,"qty":10.0}, "Price 3":{"price":7.99,"qty":20.0}}

or
{"Price 1":{"price":9.99,"qty":1.0}}

or
{}

This is my struct
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Price {
    pub price: f64,
    pub qty: f64
}

Not getting how to serialize the prices to Vec<Price> using serde
serde_json::from_str(&price.value).unwrap()


That looks like it's just a HashMap<String, Price>? What's the problem? What even is price.value? And why are you talking about Vec?

Please clarify whether order matters, and if so what the ordering criterion is.

You cannot do that with out-of-the-box serde, you will need to implement you own Deserialize trait for Price
or the easier way:
first parse it into HashMap<String,Price> then transform it into Vec<Price>
use std::collections::HashMap;

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Price {
    pub price: f64,
    pub qty: f64,
}

pub fn main() {
    let json = r#"
    {"Price 1":{"price":9.99,"qty":1.0}, "Price 2":{"price":8.99,"qty":10.0}, "Price 3":{"price":7.99,"qty":20.0}}
    "#;

    let prices: Vec<_> = serde_json::from_str::<HashMap<String, Price>>(json)
        .unwrap()
        .into_values()
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", prices);
}


You can do this out of the box, it's just deserializing a HashMap<String, Price>. The first paragraph is wrong. Then in the "easier" way you say "then transform it into Price" -- no, that's not necessary either.

@cdhowie "You cannot do this out-of-the-box" clearly refers to having serde implement a Deserialize (after adding a #[serde(something)] to a newtype) that does the right thing, akin to the one shown in the other answer. The approach of deserializing to an intermediate HashMap is indeed easy, but it requires one to control how serde is invoked. "Then transform it into Price" was clearly meant to say "into Vec<Price>", which Dizzyi fixed in the meantime - and it is necessary to answer the question, which mentions Vec<Price> explicitly.

If you want to deserialize into a Vec without passing through a HashMap, you can use the following deserialization code:
use serde::{de::Visitor, Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Price {
    pub price: f64,
    pub qty: f64,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct PriceVec(Vec<Price>);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for PriceVec {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct MapVisitor;
        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for MapVisitor {
            type Value = PriceVec;

            fn expecting(
                &self,
                formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter,
            ) -> std::fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("Map<String, Price>")
            }

            fn visit_map<A>(self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: serde::de::MapAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut prices =
                    Vec::with_capacity(map.size_hint().unwrap_or(0));
                while let Some((_, val)) = map.next_entry::<String, _>()? {
                    prices.push(val);
                }

                Ok(PriceVec(prices))
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_map(MapVisitor)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"
        {"Price 1":{"price":9.99,"qty":1.0},
         "Price 2":{"price":8.99,"qty":10.0},
         "Price 3":{"price":7.99,"qty":20.0}
        }"#;
    let prices = serde_json::from_str::<PriceVec>(json).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", prices.0);
}

[Price { price: 9.99, qty: 1.0 }, Price { price: 8.99, qty: 10.0 }, Price { price: 7.99, qty: 20.0 }]


Since order isn't guaranteed in many JSON implementations I wonder if it would be a good idea to at least have some validation on the keys being in the right order.

@cdhowie This should get the order right because it works on a very low level: it uses visit_map() to receive data that comprises the map, which has no choice but to be in the order in which it appears in the JSON stream. (Otherwise serde_json's Deserializer would have to be doing something weird and potentially inefficient.) serde_json does lose order, but that happens because it uses HashMap, not due tovisit_map() receiving values in the wrong order. serde_json can be configured to preserve order (it switches to IndexMap) which is another indication that visit_map() retains order.

@user4815162342 That is all true but is also unrelated to my point. The received JSON may not have the keys in the right order if the source decides to change how they're generating the JSON. The point is that JSON itself doesn't care about the order of keys in an object, so wherever this JSON is getting generated would be perfectly in their "rights" to suddenly provide a document with the key-value pairs in a different order (unless they've documented a guarantee that this will never happen).

@cdhowie Fair enough, I didn't realize that that was your point. Not sure what validation the OP can implement on their end, though, as I suspect the JSON format is dictated by code they don't control.

@user4815162342 Adding validation to the code in the answer is easy: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69f6bf8204852650f78e2e847b954d05 Better would be to maintain a sparse array (maybe a BTreeMap) of the seen indices and then building a Vec as the final step, after checking that the keys are all contiguous.

@cdhowie Right, but that assumes that names like Price 1 form an actual naming scheme rather than being made-up example names. While certainly not impossible, I find that unlikely. That's for the OP to confirm, but at least I now understand what you meant by validation - thanks for clearing it up.
